# jquery - making dropped objects draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, draggable, droppable

how can i make a dragged object into a droppable become "draggable" again?
i tried adding the object by using "append" in jquery. but after seeing/appending the object inside the droppable div. i cannot drag it.

here is my work http://piratelufi.com/flowers/

the images that are already in the gray area can be dragged and resized.
the images in the lower left area, when dragged into the gray area will add it there but cannot be dragged.

i even tried adding to ui-draggable class into the element that needs to be dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Draggebles remains draggable even after drop. Check [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Comment: i initialized the small pictures in the lower left as 'sortable' .does this mean i need to make it 'draggable' too?